# Verizon/ActionTec router and "MAC Address already exists in Wireless Broadband Router's database"

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, gateway

I'm trying to add a DHCP reservation for an old Apple G5. Some others want to use it for testing software on PowerPC, and this seems like the easiest way to ensure port forwarding does not break over time.

According to [How to do DHCP reservations with Actiontec MI424WR](https://forums.verizon.com/t5/Home-Networking/How-to-do-DHCP-reservations-with-Actiontec-MI424WR-Rev-F-router/td-p/458307) on the Verizon forums, I need to add the reservation via *Advanced → IP Address Distribution → Connection List → New Static Connection*. However, when I try to do it, I get the same error discussed at [IP address questions for FIOS router MI424WR](https://forums.verizon.com/t5/FiOS-Internet/IP-address-questions-for-FIOS-router-MI424WR/td-p/527099):

> MAC Address already exists in Wireless Broadband Router's database.

Unfortunately, Verizon has off-loaded support to donors, so there's no answers from Verizon. There is an answer from a donor, but its a guess that does not help.

I've tried clearing the database by deleting relevant DNS entries, and deleting the existing DHCP leases. But the error persists.

How do I clear the *MAC Address already exists in Wireless Broadband Router's database* error message so I can add the reservation?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get this to work but it's really a hack.

First go to Advanced->IP Address Distribution

On your network (mine is "Network (Home/Office)") click on the "Edit" button to bring up the DHCP settings.

I changed the "start IP Address" so it's 1 below the "End IP Address". In my case I made the last octet 253 since the "End IP Address" was X.X.X.254.

Note, FOR ME it didn't reset the connection to the computer I was using to edit the router settings. As long as your lease has plenty of time on it and it doesn't attempt to renegotiate for a new IP Address you ***SHOULD*** be okay.

If you go to Advanced->IP Address Distribution->Connection list it should now be empty (assuming you had no existing devices at X.X.X.253 or X.X.X.254).

I was able to add my static connection using "Add Static Connection" now without an issue. I then set the range back to what it was originally.

I wouldn't restart the router before setting the range back or you might not be able to get back in from the computer you're using to edit the settings. Once you set the range back you can restart it. I rebooted it from the UI.